# PyDev project's PYTHONPATH automatically renamed. How do I properly configure this?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pylons, reddit

I'm new to PyDev and fairly rusty in Python. Trying to get back into it with a simple reddit app first. So here's my setup:

I have 2 PyDev projects: `reddit` and `pylons` (reddit api.py imports from pylons).

When I go into any file in the `reddit` project I get "unresolved import" for anything that tries to import from pylons. In `reddit`'s PYTHONPATH, I've tried adding /pylons and /pylons/pylons, but whenever I refresh the project, PyDev seems to rename my references to /reddit and /reddit/pylons.

How do I fix this? How do I properly add the `pylons` project into the PYTHONPATH of `reddit`?

Answer (score 0):

The most proper way to include another project source into your PYTHONPATH is to make a reference from your project to another project. For this make next steps:

1. Choose your project in `PyDev Package Explorer` (usually tree-like panel on the left).
2. Press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>.
3. Click `Project References` tab.
4. Check Pylons project in a tab content frame.

> **Note**, that path with source of both projects must be added to python path for Eclipse to build references for them.
>
> **Note #2** Also when you install some new Python packages you need to reindex them at `Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python`.

Comment: I've already checked the box next to `pylons` in the Project References window. Still renames and does not recognize. 
Also for your note #1, do you mind clarifying which path you're referring to?

Comment: @PhADDinTraining What Eclipse does is package indexing and if newly installed packages are not indexed - it will mark them as unresolved imports.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rostyslav's solution is not working for you, perhaps you should try to add pylons as an external library. At reddit's Properties window click `PyDev-PYTHONPATH` tab and the `External Libraries` tab. Click `Add source folder` and find pylons's source folder. Changes to external libraries are not monitored. So you have to use `Force restore internal info` when pydev can't find new references (tipically when you make changes to pylons's structure).